How do I get my legend showing so that three variables affect the legend?
Following on from this question, I now have my plot. I am running into problems trying to get a legend showing the way I need it. The legend should have three elements:

the colour of the legend item should be the same as in the map.
the first column should be the ID (numbered 1 through 16)
the label (second column of the legend) should be the name of the school.

Basically, I have a map where I want to show the position of schools. I can't get the names to show because they are too long and overwrite each other on the map. I decided that the easiest way was to create an ID for each of the 16 schools, numbered from 1 to 16 and show the ID on the map. Under the ID is the dot showing the school location. I have two types of schools - primary and secondary - and thought it would be nice to give a colour to differentiate the types of school.
I can create the plot the way I want, but I can't seem to get the legend to work.I've restricted the legend so it won't show one for TimaruUrbanArea data.
After various attempts based on other questions, such as, I got my code as far as
 TimaruSchoolGeoCoded <- data.frame(SchoolName = c("Barton Rural School", "Bluestone School", "Craighead Diocesan School",
                                              "Gleniti School", "Grantlea Downs School", "Highfield School",
                                              "Mountainview High School", "Oceanview Heights School", "Roncalli College",
                                              "Sacred Heart School", "St Joseph's School",
                                              "Timaru Boys' High School", "Timaru Christian School",
                                              "Timaru Girls' High School","Timaru South School", "Waimataitai School"),
                               Address = c("462 Fairview Road, Fairview, Timaru", "46 Raymond Street, West End, Timaru",
                                           "1 Wrights Avenue, Highfield, Timaru", "22 Heath Street, Gleniti, Timaru",
                                           "65 Grants Road, Marchwiel, Timaru", "26 Rimu Street, Highfield, Timaru",
                                           "97 Pages Road, Timaru", "241 Selwyn Street, Marchwiel, Timaru", 
                                           "19 Wellington Street, Parkside, Timaru", "54 Heaton Street, Parkside, Timaru",
                                           "50 Kelvin Street, Marchwiel, Timaru", "211 North Street, Timaru",
                                           "10 Quarry Road, Watlington, Timaru", "68 Cain Street, Parkside, Timaru",
                                           "44 Queen Street, Parkside, Timaru", "25 Trafalgar Street, Waimataitai, Timaru"),
                               Type = c("Primary", "Primary", "Secondary", "Primary", "Primary", "Primary", "Secondary",
                                        "Primary", "Secondary", "Primary", "Primary", "Secondary", "Primary",
                                        "Secondary", "Primary", "Primary"))

 TimaruSchoolGeoCoded <- TimaruSchoolGeoCoded %>%
   tidygeocoder::geocode(Address, method = "arcgis") %>%
   mutate(SchoolID = row_number())

 TimaruSchoolSP <- st_as_sf(TimaruSchoolGeoCoded, coords = c("long", "lat"), crs = 4326)

 TimaruUrbanAreaSchools <- tm_shape(TimaruUrbanArea) +
   tm_polygons("AU2013_label",
          col = "grey",
          fill.scale = tm_scale_ordinal(values = c("Fairview-Scarborough" = "#F7FCF5","Fraser Park" = "#F7FCF5", 
                                                   "Gleniti" = "#F7FCF5", "Glenwood" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Highfield" = "#F7FCF5", "Maori Park" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Marchwiel" = "#F7FCF5", "Otipua Creek-Washdyke Flat" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Parkside" = "#F7FCF5", "Redruth" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Seaview" = "#F7FCF5", "Timaru Gardens" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Waimataitai" = "#F7FCF5", "Washdyke" = "#F7FCF5",
                                                   "Watlington" = "#F7FCF5")),
          fill.legend = tm_legend_hide()) + 
   tm_layout(frame = FALSE) +

   tm_shape(TimaruSchoolSP) +
   tm_dots("Type", fontface = "bold", fill.legend = tm_legend_hide()) +
   tm_text("SchoolID", size = .6, col = "Type", fontface = "bold", xmod = .2, ymod=.5, col.legend = tm_legend_hide()) +
   tm_add_legend(title = "School", labels = TimaruSchoolSP$SchoolName, text = TimaruSchoolSP$SchoolID)

Which produces the image below. The school names are in the legend, but they're not the same colour as in the graph, and there are grey circles to the left instead of the ID numbers. Barton Rural should have a 1, Bluestone a 2, and so forth instead of that grey circle in the legend. Barton Rural should also be in that red colour, along with the other primary schools, and Craighead Diocesan should be that purple colour, along with the other secondary schools, in the legend.

I also found this,but it seems to rely on having to create bespoke groups instead of using ones that exist in the data.

I can't see tm_scale_ordinal in the tmap version currently on CRAN. Did you get a development version from github or does it come from another package?

I can't see any way of colouring the letters. You could use paste to prefix the labels with numbers to get that, but the numbers wouldn't be coloured either. Conventionally you'd have a single legend for the type (with two entries) and the list of 1 to 12 labels.

@SpacedmanI had to go to tmap version 4. And then spent ages trying to work out how to get the code migrated from version 3.x to version 4. I'm not sure where I got the ordinal specification from. It works for when you want to plot different colours by polygon.

I gave up and put in the labels, and saved the plot as a larger object with higher dpi.
